# trying to use wp_handle_upload with ajax

Tags: theme-development, functions, uploads, ajax

I've used [this tutorial](http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-ajax-in-your-wordpress-theme-admin/) to build an option page form with Ajax.

Now, i want to use the wp_handle_upload to upload an image. 
i tried this http://pastebin.com/35HW8RSZ but with no success.

help will be appreciated.
Asaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution [here](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/). It Exceeds any external Ajax solution, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a few files to get `wp_handle_upload`  to work, and i have a function just for that :

```
function My_wp_handle_upload($file_handler,$overrides) {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $upload = wp_handle_upload( $file_handler, $overrides );
  return $upload ;
}
```

so after you add this function to your file just change your call from :

```
$file = wp_handle_upload($data['MoobLogoUpload'], $overrides);
```

to:

```
$file = My_wp_handle_upload($data['MoobLogoUpload'], $overrides);
```

### Update

Just remembered that you must use an ajax upload solution like:

- JQurey form plugin
- Uplodify
- SWFUpload

any other or submit by iframe since it is not possible to upload files using the browser's XMLHttpRequest object